# Raster from Ascii text file doesn't project properly

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, coordinate-system, esri-ascii-raster

I created an ascii grid of annual precipitation for CONUS in *MATLAB* and imported it into *Arcmap*. The text file can be downloaded here:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/0k4x257x597ogij/meanTotalPmm.txt?dl=0

After using the "ascii to raster" tool, I attempted to assign a coordinate system but without luck. Even though the correct information are recorded under the source tab in the layer properties, the file definitely doesn't project properly. As seen in the picture, it should align with the Oregon layer which is in the NAD_1983_Albers coordinate system. I used the "define projection" and the "project"  tool, and I attempted to edit the information from within ArcCatalog without success.

[image]

Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?